# CMake truncates values passed to function

Tags: cmake

I created a function in CMake that is supposed to receive two parameters, one being a string and the other a list of source files. The problem is that CMake truncates the list of variables passed to the function and I only get the first file:

```
set(
  INCLUDES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/smthcore/Interface.hpp
)

set(
  SRC
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Interface.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/Class.hpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/detail/Class.cpp
)

set(
  TO_FORMAT
    ${INCLUDES} 
    ${SRC}
)

message("111 " ${TO_FORMAT})
include(ClangFormat)
format_source(src ${TO_FORMAT})
```

where `message` prints

```
/mnt/c/Users/Desktop/smth.Core/include/smthcore/Interface.hpp/mnt/c/Users/Desktop/smth.Core/src/Interface.cpp/mnt/c/Users/Desktop/smth.Core/src/detail/Class.hpp/mnt/c/Users/Desktop/smth.Core/src/detail/Class.cpp
```

but inside `format_source` I have

```
function(FORMAT_SOURCE trgt to_format)
message("222 " ${trgt})
message("333 " ${to_format})
endfunction(FORMAT_SOURCE trgt to_format)
```

and 333 prints

```
333 /mnt/c/Users/Desktop/smth.Core/include/smthcore/Interface.hpp
```

I am very confused. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to remember when writing CMake scripts is that in textual CMake input, both whitespace and `;` are valid argument separators<sup>(1)</sup>. In other words, you're not calling your function with 2 arguments, but with 5 of them (each element of the list `TO_FORMAT` becomes a separate argument for `format_source`).

There are multiple ways to solve this. The minimal one is to quote the expansion of `TO_FORMAT` to turn it into a single argument, like this:

```
format_source(src "${TO_FORMAT}")
```

However, that is error prone and does not really match the style used by most native CMake commands. I would therefore suggest a different approach, to make `format_source` accept an arbitrary number of arguments (similarly to how CMake commands like `add_executable` or `target_link_libraries` do):

```
function(FORMAT_SOURCE trgt)
message("222 " ${trgt})
message("333 " ${ARGN})
endfunction()
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that you can actually notice this in the very behaviour of `message()`, which by default prints a direct concatenation of its arguments. When you call it like this:

```
message("111 " ${TO_FORMAT})
```

there are no separators between the elements of `TO_FORMAT`: each of them formed a separate argument to `message`. If, however, you were to call it like this:

```
message("111 " "${TO_FORMAT}")
```

there would be semi-colons separating the elements, because the entire list (which is *exactly the same* as a semicolon-separated string) becomes one argument of `message`.